# MySQL Workbench Model Sync - different results

Tags: mysql-workbench

To design our MySQL-database, we are using MySQL Workbench (6.3). The Modelfile is synchronized through git, but we also moved it between computers manually.

The Issue we are facing currently, is that synchronizing the model-file with the very same database on a server yields different results for 2 developer machines.

On one machine, everything is "ok", the other machine drops some tables and stuff upon synchronization, claiming they are no longer present in the model - but they are.

We compared all involved software down to the exact build number, there is no difference we could find. What could be a possible reason for this behaviour?

- Same server / database
- Same Workbench Version
- Same Model-File
- Same User to access the database

The Machine that is not working correctly is a fresh setup - so most likely not any cache issues "there". We are out of ideas on this. Anyone ever experienced?